# How to make uib-datepicker's show-spinners to be dynamically updated?

Tags: angularjs

As you can see in that snippet, I've set the attributes `show-meridian` and `show-spinners` to match to the variable `$scope.myBool`.

I've added as well a green button that says `change!` and toggles  `$scope.myBool`.

While `show-meridian` is perfectly reacting to any change in `$scope.myBool`, `show-meridian` is not being updated.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.9/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TimepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
      $scope.mytime = new Date();

      $scope.hstep = 1;
      $scope.mstep = 15;

      $scope.options = {
        hstep: [1, 2, 3],
        mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
      };

      $scope.ismeridian = true;
      $scope.toggleMode = function() {
        $scope.ismeridian = !$scope.ismeridian;
      };

      $scope.update = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setHours(14);
        d.setMinutes(0);
        $scope.mytime = d;
      };

      $scope.changed = function() {
        $log.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
      };

      $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.mytime = null;
      };
      $scope.myBool = false;
    });
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .timepickercontainer .uib-timepicker .btn-link {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="TimepickerDemoCtrl">
    <div class="timepickercontainer">
      <div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" arrowkeys="false" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep"  show-meridian="myBool"
                       show-spinners="!myBool" ></div>
    </div>
    <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime | date:'shortTime' }}</pre>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        Hours step is:
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="hstep" ng-options="opt for opt in options.hstep"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        Minutes step is:
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="mstep" ng-options="opt for opt in options.mstep"></select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="toggleMode()">12H / 24H</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="update()">Set to 14:00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    
    <button class='btn btn-success' ng-click='myBool = !myBool'>change!</button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i reproduce i think may is an issue related to the directive not your code, try reporting the bug in the issue section. I still make research.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky soluction. how i say in the comment is better to maka a issue in the repo of the directive.

for make spinner hide and show you must enter in the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file and find this line

```
$scope.showSpinners = angular.isDefined($attrs.showSpinners) ?
$scope.$parent.$eval($attrs.showSpinners) : timepickerConfig.showSpinners;
```

and substitute with this

```
$scope.showSpinners = timepickerConfig.showSpinners;
  if ($attrs.showSpinners) {
    watchers.push($scope.$parent.$watch($parse($attrs.showSpinners), 
function(value) {
      $scope.showSpinners = !!value;


        updateTemplate();

    }));
  }
```

heres is my plnkr 
[example](https://plnkr.co/edit/PIubXSniuVQdV6ke2VOR?p=preview)

Comment: i also open an issue in the repo for this functioonality.